# Pass object to thread and get it back after thread has run

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, threadpool

I will say this right off the bat. I am an amateur at threading. I am a senior *c# web developer*, but I have a project that requires me to populate a lot of objects that take a long time to populate as they require *WebRequests* and *Responses* to populate.  I have everything working without *threading*, but it does not run fast enough for my requirements.  I would like to pass everything to a `ThreadPool` to have the *threading* managed for me as I may be queuing up 20,000 threads at the same time and for obvious reasons. I do not want to hit a website with the requests needed to populate all of them at once.

What I would like to do is to pass in an *object*, populate it, and then add it to a *collection* in the main *thread* once it is populated.  Then once all the objects are populated, continue on with execution of the program.  I do not know how many objects will need to be populated until they are all populated either.

My question...What is the best approach to doing this?

Here is the loop that I am trying to speed up:

```
foreach (HElement hElement in repeatingTag.RunRepeatingTagInstruction())
{
    object newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(currentObject.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);
    List<XElement> ordering = GetOrdering(tagInstructions.Attribute("type").Value);
    RunOrdering(ordering, newObject, hElement);
    MethodInfo method = currentObject.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
    method.Invoke(currentObject, new[] { newObject });
}
```

I don't know what the object is beforehand so I create it using the Activator. The RunOrdering method runs through the instructions that I pass that tell it how to populate the object. Then I add it to the collection.  Also, the object itself may have properties that will require this method to run through and populate their data.

Comment: If your program's purpose is making 20,000 web requests, then it's not constrained by how well you distribute this tasks to CPU cores, but by network bandwidth. You might gain s small speed-up by performing 2-5 requests in parallel, but above that there won't be much improvement. What you need is some kind of "scheduler" that keeps a list of outstanding tasks, and always keeps a small number of tasks running in parallel. The tasks write their results to a shared collection. The scheduler sets a signal when all tasks are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you probably have to wait for them all to be complete, all you need is a `Parallel.ForEach()` or equivalent. And a Thread-safe collection. Note that for I/O intensive tasks you would want to limit the number of Threads. 20.00 threads would be insane in any situation.

But we would need to see more details (code). Note that there is no such thing as "a collection in the main thread".

Comment: I tried changing my foreach loop to using a Parallel.ForEach, and it seemed to be working for a little bit, but I'm getting an error saying that it can't update the collection.  I am assuming that this is due to the Add method trying to update the collection at the same time as another thread.  Is there any way to check for a lock situation?  (I may not have the correct terminology on this)

Comment: Yes. I don't know what RunOrdering() is doing, but you will have to verify that each Task is independent as much as possible, and use `lock` wherever you need to share something.

Comment: Everything is independent except for the call to add to the collection.  I put a lock on this call and it is working like a dream.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> populate a lot of objects that take a
>   long time to populate as they require
>   WebRequests and Responses

Avoid Threading if you are doing requests.
No speedup after two threads, merely existent with the two.
A lot of truble for nothing.

Comment: I also upvoted this answer because it doesn't seem to be running a whole lot faster and it was a little bit of a pain to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

If you are on .net 4 try using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) instead. You would have much better control over scheduling. Try to not share any objects, make them immutable and all the warnings and [best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx) about synchronisation, shared data etc.

And secondly you might want to think of an out of process solution like [message queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) (xMQ products or poor man's database table as queue) so you would have the chance to distribute your task over multiple machines if you need to.